# Traversing a directory xml structure using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, nested

I have a directory structure like this :

```
Root
 |
 |-Folder 1
 |   |
 |   |--Multiple files.
 |   |
 |   |--Folder 1.a
 |         |
 |-Files   |
           |----Multiple files.
           |----Further tree of more folder's and files.
```

it's saved in an XML file like following :

```
<dir name="root">
 <dir name="Folder 1">
  <file name="file1"/>
  <file name="file2"/>
  <dir name="folder1.a>
   <file name="innerfile"/>
  </dir>
 </dir>
 <dir name="folder2">
  .... so on ....
```

i want to traverse this tree using jQuery and print the directory structure as it is using indents, something like this :

```
Root
  Folder1
   file1
   file2
   Folder1.a
    inner file
  Folder2
    file N
    folder N 
       .....
```

the code i am using is as follow

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "root.xml",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: parseXml
     });
   });

   function parseXml(xml)
   {
    $(xml).find("directory").each(function(){
       $("#output").append("<a href = \"" + $(this).attr("absolutePath") + "\">" +                                                          $(this).attr("name") + "</a><br>");
       $(this).find("file").each(function()
       {
         $("#output").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href = \"" + $(this).attr("absolutePath") + "\">" + $(this).attr("name") + "</a><br>");
       });
       $('#output').append("<br>");
     });
```

My code is working but files are redundant for nested folders as i am printing all the files in a sub directory multiple times, i want one file to be listed only once, but couldn't figure out how it's possible???

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: instead uf indenting with whitespace, consider using html lists: `<ul><li>..</li></ul>`

Comment: Sorry, i've updated the question. i want to print one file exactly once and this code is printing nested files multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the level of the node you are looking at, you can do this using a series of 2 column tables, where the first cell of each table is a spacer equal to the current level * the number of pixels you want to space by, like this:

```
$("output").append("<table><tr><td style=\"width: " + (myLevel * 12).ToString() + "px;\" /><td><a href = \"" + $(this).attr("absolutePath") + "\">" + ...
```

The end result would look something like this:

```
<table><tr><td style="width: 0px;" /><td>Root</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 12px;" /><td>Folder1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 24px;" /><td>file1</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 24px;" /><td>file2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 24px;" /><td>Folder1.a</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 36px;" /><td>inner file</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 12px;" /><td>Folder2</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 24px;" /><td>filen</td></tr></table>
<table><tr><td style="width: 24px;" /><td>Folder1.n</td></tr></table>
```

Sorry I couldn't help with the xml portion, but hopefully this will get you moving in the right direction.